# How should I replace the sentence torch.Assert from pytorch-1.7.1 to some other sentence in pytorch-1.5.0

Tags: python, pytorch

The thing is I need to reimplement a GAN model using torch1.5.0 but the previous torch1.7.1 version codes contains a torch.Assert sentence to do symbolic assert. What sentence should I use to do the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

Just use python's native `assert`. That's what it does under the hood.

```
torch._assert(x == y, 'assertion message')
```

to be replaced with

```
assert x == y, 'assertion message'
```